# How to prove that a vector $\vec{u} = c\vec{w} + d\vec{v}$, ending at $\vec{v}-\vec{w}$, always has the property that $c+d=1$?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

[image]

I was doing a vector problem on Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra.
It asks me to find the restriction on c and d such that the vector $\vec{u} = c\vec{w} + d\vec{v}$, always ends at the dashed line.

My instinct tells me the relation between $c$ and $d$ is $c + d = 1$ and several examples confirmed my contention.

However, I find that I don't know how to prove this relation, that is, $c+d=1$. Any ideas? I'll appreciate any and all hints that help me get the ball rolling.

Comment: Isn't $u=cw+dv $?

Comment: One way to look at this problem is that $\vec{u}$ is a convex combination of $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the vector $\vec{w}$ can be written as $\vec{v}+(\vec{w}-\vec{v})$.  More generally, the vector $\vec{w}-\vec{v}$ points in the direction of the line of interest.  Therefore, a vector of interest is of the form $\vec{v}+\lambda(\vec{w}-\vec{v})=\lambda\vec{w}+(1-\lambda)\vec{v}$.  Now, add the coefficients to get one.